# Video Editor with custom effect masking and shape/drawing overlays

Tags: video-editor, effects

I've spent a very long time on this and have been unimpressed with 90% of the main stream video editors, so I'd really appreciate some expert advice on this.

I'm looking for a video editor (hopefully within the 100-150 range if possible) that has the following options:

1. "Effects Masking" - ability to draw custom masks for blurring small segments of text on screen captures. A lot of the editors I see allow you to import a png file for this, but I really would rather have this in the editor, as I have a lot of footage and making a new png for every time the text changes would take forever.
2. Customizable basic shapes/drawing tools for overlays - NOT cheesy animated overlays; I want to be able to highlight areas of the screen by being able to draw boxes or circles around them.

These seem like basic requirements, but I've had a really hard time with this, so I would REALLY appreciate your help!

Comment: Someone on Google+ mentioned that HitFilm Express is free right now: http://community.hitfilm.com/index.php?/blog/1/entry-328-get-hitfilm-2-express-for-free I'll look into it and post as an answer if I find it meets my needs. It looks like an awesome program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't really rotoscoping, just mask drawing.  Rotoscoping is more on a frame by frame basis generally.  Either way, After Effects will do what you are looking for very easily, but is not in your price range (not even nearly).  Largely, you get what you pay for though and I'm not sure that there are a whole lot of cheaper options that allow you to draw your masks in the editor.

Comment: I kinda figured. You can confirm that After Effects can do this, though? Their month-to-month pricing isn't bad for how much I'd be using it.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the correction about rotoscoping. :)

Comment: @CullenJ - yes, After Effects can handle what you are talking about and much, much more.  It is even relatively easy to do if I understand you correctly.  It has tools that allow you to draw masks right over the video and you can then leave them there as long as it is valid and use it as a mask for a filter (such as a blur).  It is basically Photoshop for video.

Answer (score 1):

Apple motion can do this, and it's in your price range at $50.  It's not a video editor per-se, more of a motion graphics and compositing app, but then again, so is After Effects.